# Use a configuration file of another project in a service of project in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, minio

I config `Minio` with `minioIp`, `minioPort`, `minioAccessKey`, `minioSecretKey` and then I create a Bean `MinioClient` like this:

```
@Bean
public MinioClient minioClient() {
    return MinioClient.builder()
          .endpoint(minioIp, minioPort, false)
          .credentials(minioAccessKey, minioSecretKey)
          .build();
}
```

How can I use it in service of another project in Spring Boot?